# When to use Lazy Loading in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Is there any scenario where you would use Lazy loading in your production application?

If so, what's the scenario?

From what I understand lazy loading can negatively influence the performance of queries. I am asking this question as I disabled lazy loading because of problems with json serialization (circural reference exception) and I would like to know in what scenario it might back fire me.

Comment: yes.....  Any other question?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Lazy loading is useful when you want to load entities and related entities only when they are needed by your application.  If you don't need all your data all the time then lazy loading might be useful.  You have to be careful as it can cause quite a bit more trips to your database.

The article seems to have a lot of good information on when to use what loading technique.
[Lazy Loading vs Eager Loading](https://codingatilivedigitally.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading/)

Comment: This may sound silly, but from my point of view, lazy loading is way tricky, specially in cases where serialization is involved - like transferring data via json between Web API and consumers. It can easily become a snowball. So, I decided to *never* use it.

Comment: Indeed sometimes it can be tricky.  I tend to lean more toward eager loading and load my object graph at the beginning.  But I typically don't have any performance constraints with loading my data at one time.  In theory lazy loading would be good if you didn't have that luxury.